# From VirtualBox to live server

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VM on VirtualBox, it was created long time ago by another person and now I need to move the VM on a live server.
My goal is to recreate the same env on the live server, with the same configuration of all the services ( tomcat etc ).
There is any way to do that?

I have seen that VirtualBox has the export feature but seems that is used to mode the VM from one installation to the other.

EDIT:
Virtualbox is installed on a local pc

Comment: What do you want to run the vm on.  A physical machine,  VMware, hyper-V?

Comment: I need to run on a DigitalOcean VPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OVF is  a standard for exporting and importing VMs.  So you would export to ovf from virtual box.  Go to the destination virtualisation system and import the ovf into it.

Comment: The destination is a DigitalOcean VPS

Comment: They seem to support custom images, you need to export it as one of their supported formats .  They suggest using virtual box to get into one of the supported file types so that looks ok.